# How to remove special characters from the beginning of a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I am getting my data from XML which may some time contain special Character at beginning like:

> 'This is a sample title  or %&*I don't know if this is the text

I tried with :
`title[0].isstring() or title[0].isdigit()` and then remove the character.  But if there are more than one special character at the beginning, then how do I remove it? Do I need a for loop?

Comment: I would suggest you check why you are getting "special characters" out of an XML document
Is the document encoded as utf-8 - are you decoding the xml correctly?  sometimes seeing special characters is often an encoding issue not a problem with the content of the xml.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re
mystring = re.sub(r"^\W+", "", mystring)
```

This removes all non-alphanumeric characters from the start of your string:

**Explanation:**

```
^   # Start of string
\W+ # One or more non-alphanumeric characters
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'^\W*', '', "%&*I don't know if this is the text")
"I don't know if this is the text"

#or

>>> "%&*I don't know if this is the text".lstrip("!@#$%^&*()")
"I don't know if this is the text"
```

Comment: `\W+` is better. `\W*` also matches the empty string, so a replace operation and string reassignment have to be done even if there is nothing to replace.

Answer (score 1):

If there are just a few specific kinds of characters you want to remove, use [`lstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) ("left strip").

For instance, if you wanted to remove any starting `%`, `&`, or `*` characters, you'd use:

```
actual_title = title.lstrip("%&*")
```

On the other hand, if you want to remove any characters that *aren't* part of a certain set (e.g. alphanumerics), then the regex solution specified in Tim Pietzcker's solution is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Using a strip function to remove any special characters from the beginning and end of the string. 
Ex.

> ```
> str = ").* this is text .("
> str.strip(")(.* ")
>
> Output: 'this is text'
> ```

If you want to remove from the beginning of string use lstrip()
Ex.

> ```
> str = ").* this is text .("
> str.lstrip(")(.* ")
>
> Output: 'this is text .('
> ```

If you want to remove from the end of the string use rstrip()
Ex.

> ```
> str = ").* this is text .("
> str.rstrip(")(.* ")
>
> Output: ').* this is text'
> ```